# Optimizing linear objective over non-convex polyhedron

Tags: linear-programming, non-convex-optimization

I am wondering what happens if I want to search for an optimal solution on the following polygon for a linear problem?

[image: Polyeder]

Comment: Partition the non-convex polygon into two (disjoint) triangles. Optimize over each triangle. Then take the maximum (or minimum) of the two maxima (or minima).

Comment: Thank you @RodrigodeAzevedo.

Comment: I have one more question.  In conclusion of this you can't say there are only convex linear problems? There are also concav linear problems?

Comment: No, LPs are convex by definition. Read the first few slides of [MILP for control](http://acl.mit.edu/milp/MILP_for_Control.pdf).